# Don't understand "Inconsistent Accessibility" error when passing Enum as parameter inside my method

Tags: c#

Struggling to understand why I am getting the following error message

> Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type "GameModesMenu.GameMode" is
> less accessible than method
> "GameModesMenu.SelectedGameModeTextObject(GameMode _gameModeSelected)"

This is what my code looks like:

```
enum GameMode{None, PlayerVsAi1v1};

private GameMode gameModeSelected = GameMode.None;

public void PlayerVsAiOneVsOne()
{
    gameModeSelected = GameMode.PlayerVsAi1v1;
    SelectedGameModeTextObject(gameModeSelected);
}  

public void SelectedGameModeTextObject(GameMode _gameModeSelected)
{
    Debug.Log(_gameModeSelected);            
}
```

The error message goes away when I add the `public` access modifier to the `enum` like so:

```
public enum GameMode { None, PlayerVsAi1v1 };
```

But I don't understand why that works. I also don't understand why I can access it with no problems within the methods, but the error only occurs when I pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method is `public`, the `enum` parameter must also be `public`, so that it will be visible to the outer world.

Comment: Oh dang, this clears it up perfectly, I think I need more coffee, thank you Mustafa

Answer (score 1):

Since the default accessibility is private,

```
enum GameMode{None, PlayerVsAi1v1};
```

is the same as

```
private enum GameMode{None, PlayerVsAi1v1};
```

So, when you try to pass it into a public method, the compiler is telling you that nobody from the outside of this class can access the enum.  If you were to change

```
public void SelectedGameModeTextObject(GameMode _gameModeSelected)
```

to

```
private void SelectedGameModeTextObject(GameMode _gameModeSelected)
```

The error would also go away, but then nobody outside could use `SelectedGameModeTextObject`.